# omp sections using private (num_threads) clause vs default (without clauses)

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I execute the following code using two cases:

"$omp sections" and "!$omp sections private(thread_num)"

Is it done each section by a different thread in both cases?

```
program main
use omp_lib
implicit none
integer, parameter:: ma=100, n=10000, mb= 100
real, dimension (ma,n) :: a 
real, dimension (n,mb) :: b
real, dimension (ma,mb) :: c = 0. 

integer:: i,j,k, threads=2, ppt, thread_num

integer:: toc, tic, rate 
real:: time_parallel, time 

call random_number (a) 
call random_number (b)

!/////////////////////// PARALLEL PRIVATE ///////////////////////
 c=0
CALL system_clock(count_rate=rate)
call system_clock(tic)

ppt = ma/threads
  !$ call omp_set_num_threads(threads)
  
  !$omp parallel

  !$omp sections private(thread_num)  !(HERE IS THE QUESTION TOPIC)

  ! EXAMPLE PROCESS 1 (it is only an example to test 'omp sections')
  !$omp section  
  !$ thread_num = omp_get_thread_num()
  !$ print*, "Section 1 started by thread number:", thread_num
  do i= 1,50
    do j= 1,mb
      do k= 1,n
        c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
      end do 
    end do
  end do 
  !$ print*, "Section 1 finished by thread number:", thread_num

  ! EXAMPLE PROCESS 2
  !$omp section  
  !$ thread_num = omp_get_thread_num()
  !$ print*, "Section 2 started by thread number:", thread_num
  do i= 51,100
    do j= 1,mb
      do k= 1,n
        c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
      end do 
    end do
  end do 
  !$ print*, "Section 2 finished by thread number:", thread_num

!$omp end sections
!$omp end parallel
print*, '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////'
print*, 'Result in Parallel' 
!$ print*, c(85:90,40)  
  
call system_clock(toc)
time_parallel = real(toc-tic)/real(rate)

!/////////////////////// normal execution ///////////////////////
 c = 0
CALL system_clock(count_rate=rate)
call system_clock(tic)

  call system_clock(tic)

  do i= 1,ma
    do j= 1,mb
      do k= 1,n
        c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
      end do 
    end do
  end do 
  
  
call system_clock(toc)
time =  real(toc-tic)/real(rate)
print*, 'Result in serial mode'
print*, c(85:90,40)  
print*, '------------------------------------------------'
print*, 'Threads: ', threads, '|  Time Parallel ', time_parallel, 's '
print*, '                         Time Normal  ', time, 's'
!----------------------------------------------------------------

end program main
```

That is the result for "!$omp sections" and "!$omp sections private(thread_num)", respectively :

Section 1 started by thread number:           1

Section 2 started by thread number:           1

Section 1 finished by thread number:           1

Section 2 finished by thread number:           1

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Result in Parallel

2507.23853       2494.16162       2496.83960       2503.58960       2509.34448
2518.64160

Result in serial mode

2507.23853       2494.16162       2496.83960       2503.58960       2509.34448
2518.64160

Threads:            2 |  Time Parallel   0.428116574

Time Normal    0.605000019     s

---

Section 1 started by thread number:           0

Section 2 started by thread number:           1

Section 1 finished by thread number:           0

Section 2 finished by thread number:           1

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Result in Parallel

2523.38281       2501.28369       2517.81860       2502.66235       2503.13940
2532.35791

Result in serial mode

2523.38281       2501.28369       2517.81860       2502.66235       2503.13940
2532.35791

Threads:            2 |  Time Parallel   0.432999998

Time Normal    0.610204018     s

---

It was compiled using:

gfortran -Wall -fopenmp -O2 -Wall -o prog.exe prueba.f90
./prog.exe

CPU model of my laptop:

AMD A6-6310 (4 cores and a thread per core)

P.S: the main goal is to test parallel clauses not to speedup matrix calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thread_num` should definitely be a private variable. Otherwise both threads use the same variable and hence you got the value `1` from both threads. It is a race condition to write from two threads to the same variable.

You can make it private for the whole parallel region and only call `omp_get_thread_num()` once at the start of the region.

```
  !$omp parallel private(thread_num)

  !$ thread_num = omp_get_thread_num()

  !$omp sections 
  !$omp section
  !$ print*, "Section 1 started by thread number:", thread_num

  ...
```